# Custom User Management Column Headers in Community Builder

Tags: community-builder

I have Joomla Version 3.9.8 and Community Builder Version 2.4.2

How do I configure the custom User Management Column Headers in Community Builder?

The default column headers are:

Checkbox, Name, Username, Online, Group, Email, Registered, Last Visit, Banned, Enabled, Confirmed, Approved, Id

My desired headers are:

Checkbox, Name, Username, Email, **Subscriptions**, Last Visit, **Expiry Date**, **Member Number**, **Status**, **Plan**, Id

Comment: Hello Greg and welcome to JSE.  I am sorry to see that your question has stalled out with no offers of support.  Did you reach out for support from the [CB folks](https://www.joomlapolis.com/)?  Have you made any progress since posting your question?  You can help to progress your question to a resolution by editing your question with any new, relevant details.  If you manage to resolve this yourself, please remember to answer your own question for the benefit of future researchers.